# ActiveRecord and and SQL AS

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to do a self join on models table with and another table something like

the sql should be something like that

```
SELECT 
  models.id
FROM 
  models, 
  shows, 
  models AS others
WHERE 
  models.location = shows.first_location AND
  others.location = shows.second_location;
```

`location`, `first_location`, `second_locations` are integers

I couldn't find how I can refer models and models AS others in the same query

I tried something like

```
Model.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN shows ON models.location = shows.first_location").joins("models as others").where("others.location = shows.second_location").where("models.id = 12")
```

This doesn't work, but I was hoping it would give me all models that are in the second location of a show that model.id = 12 is in the first location

Comment: You need to add some more information about your schema.  Can you list all your model/show/location associations?  What sort of field is `shows.first_location` and `shows.second_location`?  Should "Location" be a class, which they link to with `first_location_id` and `second_location_id` instead?

Comment: I didn't add that for simplifications, they are all integers for this example. location is not a class, but a number

Comment: It's not a simplification if people have to guess what your schema is.  Is location a class?

Comment: no its an integer. regular number

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with the rails association options rather than hand-coded SQL.

I think your schema needs to be rethought:  taking a step back, and looking at it in natural language, you have a situation where each location has some shows and some models.  Each show has a first location and second location.  A show more generally have a list of locations, each of which has a field allowing them to be ordered?

It's not clear what your requirements are but you should be able to do something like this.  I haven't tested this btw but i think it should work.

```
class Model
  belongs_to :location

  def location_shows
    self.location && self.location.shows
  end

class Location
  has_many :models
  has_many :shows

class Show
  has_many :show_locations, :order => :position
  has_many :locations, :through => :show_locations

  #you can have these convenience methods if you want but we might not need them.
  def first_location
    self.locations[0]
  end

  def second_location
    self.locations[1]
  end

class ShowLocation
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :location
```

Now, your associations are all simple rails assocations with no complicated SQL.  Let's see if we can keep it that way.

We want a method for a model, which gets the associated shows and then returns all models which are in OTHER locations which are listed for that show.

```
 #in Model
 def models_in_shows_other_locations
   self.location_shows.select{|show| show.locations.select{|l| l.id != self.location_id}.collect(&:models)
 end
```

Comment: Doesn't this generate n*m queries? Or can you avoid that using this method?